# error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor when usig video from webcam in Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, computer-vision, video-streaming

I have a flask server host an http server. And in my laptop using Ubuntu 16.04. I have the next code to send the frames in grey color to the server.

```
    import cv2
    import time
    from kafka import KafkaClient, SimpleProducer

    kafka = KafkaClient('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9092')
    producer = SimpleProducer(kafka)
    topic = 'TutorialTopic'

    def video_emmiter():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if(cap.isOpened() < 0):
            print("Camera can't opend")
            return -1
        while(True):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', rgb)
            print(len(jpeg))
            producer.send_messages(topic, jpeg.tobytes())
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                out = cv2.imwrite('capture.jpg', rgb)
                break

            time.sleep(0.01)

        cap.release()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("start transmision")
        video_emmiter()
```

and I get the following error:

```
start transmision
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 10638
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cam.py", line 30, in <module>
    video_emmiter()
  File "cam.py", line 16, in video_emmiter
    rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10638: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

I had read that it might be the camera driver, how can I now and set the driver if it is these.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: `cap.read()` doesn't always guarantees to return a frame, so you must always check `if ret:` after `ret, frame = cap.read()`

Comment: yes it seems that is the problem. I am printing `ret` and it shows False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps.
Check if you are feeding the video properly to the program.
When dealing with image files, this error pops up when the file is not found at that particular location.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. Any Idea about how can I found the correct way about how to find the location of the camera? Excuse my ignorance; I am new in all of these.

Comment: [Read this: Getting Started with Videos](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) `Ret` returns a boolean value on capturing of frame. You can figure out the other stuff am sure